# Decompose cyclic sum of crossproducts into two cyclic sums?

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, cross-product

Suppose you have $6$ points $a_i\in\mathbb{R}^3$ $i\in\{1,..,6\}$ such that all triangles with vertices $0, a_i, a_{i+1}$ for $i\in\{1,..,5\}$ do not degenerate (I dont know if this assumption is really needed).

Trying different starting values, I found that the sum of the large cycle:
$$
m = a_1 \times a_2 + a_2 \times a_3 + a_3 \times a_4 +  a_4 \times a_5 + a_5 \times a_6 + a_6 \times a_1 
$$
conincides with two smaller cylces:
$$
t = a_1 \times a_3 + a_3 \times a_5 + a_5 \times a_1 + a_2 \times a_4 + a_4 \times a_6 + a_6 \times a_2
$$
where $\times $ is the usual cross product on the euclidean space $\mathbb{R}^3$.
Can you help me to prove this conjecture? Or is there a simple counterexample (I have tried a bunch of examples and it always evaluated to $m=t$)?

Comment: One way to prove this would be using a CAS to evaluate all the coordinates symbolically as polynomials, and comparing those.

Comment: Nevermind, thanks for your comment, but I found a counterexample with $m\neq t$!

Comment: Then perhaps you should add that to answer your own question.